# Amazon S3 GET object Access Denied after setting up S3 bucket policy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, download

I'm using the AWS NodeJS SDK to upload and download files to s3 buckets, recently I updated the bucket policy so no one beside my domain and the ec2 elastic beanstalk role can access these images.

Everything seems to be working fine, except actually downloading the files

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied at Request.extractError (/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:714:35)
```

S3 Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.*.domain.com and *.domain.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::data/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.*.domain.com/*",
                        "https://*.domain.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny get requests originating not from www.*.domain.com and *.domain.com.",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::data/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.*.domain.com/*",
                        "https://*.domain.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get/put requests from api.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[redacted]:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::data",
                "arn:aws:s3:::data/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to list contents of the bucket, so thats not the issue in this case because uploading is working just fine

This is my code that upload files:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: "data",
  Key: String(fileName),
  Body: file.buffer,
  ContentType: file.mimetype,
  ACL: 'public-read',
};

await s3.upload(params).promise();
```

For downloading:

```
await s3.getObject({ Bucket: this.bucketS3, Key: fileId }).promise();
```

---

Uploading/Downloading was working fine before setting up policies, but I would rather limit who can view/download these files to only the api and domains

Comment: In general, it's best to avoid `Deny` policies if possible. They can be quite confusing and not necessarily work the way you expect. Is there a particular reason why you need the `Deny` policy -- are there any other policies that might be granting the permission that you want to override with a Deny? As long as the objects themselves are not public at the ACL level, you don't actually need the Deny policy.

Comment: Also, please note that `referer` is not particularly secure, since anyone can fake a request as coming with a particular referer. A better way of controlling access is to use an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.